# Modeling Rotation and Translation of surface B.C. in Abaqus

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method, abaqus

I am trying to model a test which has grips that can translate in X and Y directions, as well as rotate. I have been trying to model this using constraints and a reference point but have not been able to model a situation where the coupon is rotated and translated, using the top surface of the coupon as the surface being moved, the rotation is about the Z axis.[image: Coupon]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To clarify, I would like that top surface to remain a straight line... but act as a boundary that can rotate and translate.